# How to add title option to Latest post block in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

Wordpress "latest post" block has options to srt number of posts to show, category to select etc options in the back end. But there is no option for widget title. But othet blocks or widgets like "recent posts" have option to add widget tittle from the back end. How can I edit this block to add widget title option to back end. Pleade provide full guide to this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add a title to the back end just go to the customizer click on the block choose the three dots, list of options contain the option (group) click it then you will be able to add sub blocks in side the latest posts block add a title, hope that helps.